# adding a textbox server control from code behind?

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to add a new textbox server control to my page from code-behind.

```
TextBox txt=new TextBox();
txt.Width=100;
txt.Height=100;

Page.Controls.Add(txt);
```

When I write following Code, this error is thrown:

> "Control 'ctl02' of type 'TextBox' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server. "

What's the reason this error is thrown? How should this be done?

Answer (score 5):

Inside the form you could put a placeholder at the location you want this textbox to appear:

```
<form runat="server">
    ...
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="holder" runat="server" />
    ...
</form>
```

and then add the textbox to this placeholder:

```
TextBox txt = new TextBox(); 
txt.Width = 100; 
txt.Height = 100;
holder.Controls.Add(txt);
```

Answer (score 4):

The error message is telling you that your `TextBox` control must be added to the `<form>` element in the page instead of the page itself. Try:

```
Page.Form.Controls.Add(txt);
```

Comment: I got it..Thanks you for answer Frédéric Hamidi .

Comment: sorry to be digging up a dinosaur, but is it possible to wrap any of this in HTML? this works, but i want to be able to put the form into a table so its formatted nice

Comment: @Dan, absolutely, you can nest the `<form>` element in an `<asp:Table>` element in your page's markup. It should work just fine.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I meant dynamically. Im using a loop to generate the form controls. They are being added to the form, but none of the dynamic elements have the table html so they dont format correctly

Comment: @Dan, well, it depends on what you want to do. You can nest a instance of `Table` into the form (in the same way as the `TextBox`), but traditionally the `<form>` element is present in the page markup, not generated dynamically. If that's the case, then relocating the form inside a newly added table may work, but I never had to test it.