# How to add Telerik RadMultiColumnComboBox Column collection from codebehind.?

Tags: asp.net, telerik, telerik-ajax

I have a simple RadMultiColumnComboBox in my aspx page with tag

```
<telerik:RadMultiColumnComboBox ID="RadMultiColumnComboBox1" RenderMode="Lightweight" runat="server" Filter="StartsWith"  OnItemDataBound="RadMultiColumnComboBox1_ItemDataBound">
 </telerik:RadMultiColumnComboBox>
```

How can I add ColumnsCollection-->MultiColumnComboBoxColumn fields from code behind.

What I am trying to achieve is creating a user control for MultiColumnComboBox so that it can be reused in various screens as per my need. Thus each page has different data and I need to bind the data from code behind instead of doing it from the design page like:

```
<telerik:RadMultiColumnComboBox runat="server" ID="RadMultiColumnComboBox1"
    Width="220px" Height="400" 
    DataTextField="text" DataValueField="value">
    <ColumnsCollection>
        <telerik:MultiColumnComboBoxColumn Field="text" Title="Text">
        </telerik:MultiColumnComboBoxColumn>
        <telerik:MultiColumnComboBoxColumn Field="value" Title="Value">
        </telerik:MultiColumnComboBoxColumn>
    </ColumnsCollection>
</telerik:RadMultiColumnComboBox>
```

Please help.

Comment: Probably the same way you add every other Control from code behind: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178256/adding-a-textbox-server-control-from-code-behind. Although I do not have experience with Telerik.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution.

```
                RadMultiColumnComboBox1.DataValueField = "ID";
                RadMultiColumnComboBox1.DataTextField = "Name";

                foreach (DataColumn item in dt.Columns)
                {
                    RadMultiColumnComboBox1.ColumnsCollection.Add(new MultiColumnComboBoxColumn()
                    {
                        Field = item.ColumnName,
                        Title = item.ColumnName
                    });
                }

                RadMultiColumnComboBox1.DataSource = dt;
                RadMultiColumnComboBox1.DataBind();
```

You have to fetch the data from DB into the data table